# ConentResolver ANR's after upgrading libraries and targetSDKVersion 32

Tags: android

I am getting a lot of **ANR's** in **ContentResolver** in Firebase Crashlytics since updating all external google libraries and **targetSDKVersion 32**.

Are there any changes for ContentResolver I have missed in newer libraries/Android version?

For example, I get an ANR if I call my ContentResolver to get only a count:
at com.xxxx.xxx.db.xxxDatabase.getxxxsCount(xxxDatabase.java:1470)

```
 main (native): tid=1 systid=14120 
 #00 pc 0x4f55c libc.so (syscall + 28)
 #01 pc 0x47cc80 libart.so (art::ConditionVariable::WaitHoldingLocks(art::Thread*) + 140)
 #02 pc 0x75b88c libart.so (artJniMethodEnd + 204)
 #03 pc 0x20facc libart.so (art_jni_method_end + 12)
   at android.os.BinderProxy.transactNative(BinderProxy.java)
   at android.os.BinderProxy.transact(BinderProxy.java:584)
   at android.content.IContentService$Stub$Proxy.unregisterContentObserver(IContentService.java:1005)
   at android.content.ContentResolver.unregisterContentObserver(ContentResolver.java:2730)
   at android.database.AbstractCursor.onDeactivateOrClose(AbstractCursor.java:157)
   at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.onDeactivateOrClose(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:213)
   at android.database.AbstractCursor.close(AbstractCursor.java:186)
   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor.close(SQLiteCursor.java:207)
   at android.database.CursorWrapper.close(CursorWrapper.java:54)
   at android.content.ContentResolver$CursorWrapperInner.close(ContentResolver.java:3870)
   at com.xxxx.xxx.db.xxxDatabase.getxxxsCount(xxxDatabase.java:1470)
   at com.xxxx.xxx.db.xxxDatabase.getFiredOffxxxsCount(xxxDatabase.java:1361)
   at com.xxxx.xxx.utilities.xxxNotification.shouldGroup(xxxNotification.java:999)
   at com.xxxx.xxx.utilities.xxxNotification.getNotification(xxxNotification.java:720)
   at com.xxxx.xxx.utilities.xxxNotification.buildNotification(xxxNotification.java:522)
   at com.xxxx.xxx.utilities.xxxNotification.buildNotification(xxxNotification.java:451)
   at com.xxxx.xxx.utilities.xxxNotification.updateNotificationGroup(xxxNotification.java:1318)
   at com.xxxx.xxx.utilities.xxxNotification.cancelNotification(xxxNotification.java:335)
   at com.xxxx.xxx.utilities.xxxNotification.snooze(xxxNotification.java:1915)
   at com.xxxx.xxx.AlarmList.snoozeAllNewAlarmTime(AlarmList.java:80)
   at com.xxxx.xxx.AlarmList.onFinishSnoozeDialog(AlarmList.java:117)
   at com.xxxx.xxx.dialogs.SnoozeDialog.onClick(SnoozeDialog.java:279)
   at androidx.appcompat.app.AlertController$ButtonHandler.handleMessage(AlertController.java:167)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
   at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:201)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:288)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7898)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
   at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:548)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:936)
```

I have not changed any code, so I am wondering why this is now happening after upgrading. I think I have missed any background changes in AndroidX or Android SDK 32 version for ContentResolver or queries.

I know this is very generic, but currently I don't know where to check for the problem.
I would be grateful for any help or hint.

Update 28.09.2022:
I get also sometimes ANR's where no class is involved of my app.

```
main (native): tid=1 systid=9452 
#00 pc 0xd6a94 libc.so (__ioctl + 4)
#01 pc 0x935c4 libc.so (ioctl + 156)
#02 pc 0x51a7c libbinder.so (android::IPCThreadState::talkWithDriver(bool) + 296)
#03 pc 0x52a68 libbinder.so (android::IPCThreadState::waitForResponse(android::Parcel*, int*) + 60)
#04 pc 0x527d8 libbinder.so (android::IPCThreadState::transact(int, unsigned int, android::Parcel const&, android::Parcel*, unsigned int) + 184)
#05 pc 0x4b01c libbinder.so (android::BpBinder::transact(unsigned int, android::Parcel const&, android::Parcel*, unsigned int) + 188)
#06 pc 0x12b3e8 libandroid_runtime.so (android_os_BinderProxy_transact(_JNIEnv*, _jobject*, int, _jobject*, _jobject*, int) + 152)
   at android.os.BinderProxy.transactNative(BinderProxy.java)
   at android.os.BinderProxy.transact(BinderProxy.java:540)
   at bn.h(bn.java:11)
   at bk.a(bk.java:3)
   at bm.c(bm.java)
   at be.d(be.java:2)
   at bh.handleMessage(bh.java:28)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:236)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8056)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
   at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:656)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:967)
```

Comment: hint: do not do io operation on main threadv (even "get only a count")

Comment: I know this is not good, but there was no problem at all before.
I have not changed the code. 

So is there any changes in the framework/androidx who are causing now this?

Answer (score 0):

Seems the problems were about the upgrade from the Billing Library 3.x to 5.x!
After reverting to 3.x the ANR's are gone.

Now I have readded the Billing Library from scratch with version 5.x!
No more ANR's or strange behaviors anymore.

Strange, but I think there was a mistake on upgrading to 5.x and this caused some leaks.